# create a kvm/qemu vm from vbox config... network adapter configuration?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virtualbox

I have a virtualbox image and configuration file (.vbox) that I want to run under kvm or qemu.

I converted the disk image file to a .qcow2 image file, however I'm not sure if there are any tools that do the same for the configuration (.vbox to kvm/qemu xml).

Is there an equivalent in KVM or QEMU to configure an adapter as a host network bridge with the ability to map a host ip such as 10.20.0.2 ?

The vbox adapter configuration is below

```
<Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027BA0710" cable="true" speed="0" promiscuousModePolicy="AllowAll" type="82540EM">
      <DisabledModes>
        <NAT>
          <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
          <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
        </NAT>
        <InternalNetwork name="intnet"/>
        <HostOnlyInterface name="vboxnet0"/>
        <NATNetwork name="NatNetwork"/>
      </DisabledModes>
      <BridgedInterface name="enp0s25"/>
    </Adapter>
```

Thanks.